# Laravel Php artisan make migration error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, database-migration

what i need is need to create_attendance_table using **php artisan make:migration create_attendance_table.**

But it gets an error like this in my cmd

[image]
How can i fix this error?

Comment: need more information, show your .env

Comment: Look like you are not in your Laravel project directory. Can we see the content of your `Attendance_Management` folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you have first created a **create_attendance_table** and deleted it. The error came across because it couldn't find that deleted migration file. To get rid of error

First hit command

```
composer dump-autoload
```

and then,

```
php artisan make:migration create_attendance_table
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

for creating migration file you need this command like

```
php artisan make:migration create_users_table --create=users
```

for your table :

```
php artisan make:migration create_attendance_table --create=attendance
```

your command will `migrate` existing file, so that's why that error came.

Please read [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations) for further details.

Comment: do you have `create_attendance_table` file in migration folder? or you are trying to create migration file.