# laravel: whole migrations folder is missing

Tags: laravel

```
$ php artisan make:migration create_room_table
```

> ErrorException  : file_put_contents(D:\LaravelProjects\HotelMgmt\database\migrations/2020_06_03_060853_create_room_table.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
>
> at D:\LaravelProjects\HotelMgmt\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem.php:133
>       129|      * @return int|bool
>       130|      */
>       131|     public function put($path, $contents, $lock = false)
>       132|     {
>   133|         return file_put_contents($path, $contents, $lock ? LOCK_EX : 0);
>       134|     }
>       135| 
>       136|     /**
>       137|      * Write the contents of a file, replacing it atomically if it already exists.
>
> Exception trace:

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Php artisan make migration error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44755828/laravel-php-artisan-make-migration-error)

Comment: have you try php artisan config:cache ?

Comment: change permissions to 755.

Comment: @Florin no it doesn't help coz my whole migrations folder has been missing !

Comment: @MiteshRathod yes i did that already and composer dump_autoload  but no luck

Comment: create migration folder ?!

Comment: Just create a folder 'migrations' in D:\LaravelProjects\HotelMgmt\database\

Answer (score 0):

hey i restored my migrations folder by git restore . though some migrations are missing but it's alright for me.